# Does React Native require more websocket configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, react-native

I´ve set up a websocket connection by following this "guide":

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

My code so far, first block in React Native:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8087/");

ws.onopen = () => {
  ws.send('something');
};
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  this.setState({ message: e.data });
};
```

Second block, my node server:

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8087 });

const messages = [];

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  messages.forEach((message) => {
    ws.send(message);
  });
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    messages.push(message);
    console.log('Message Received: %s', message);

    wss.clients.forEach((conn) => {
      conn.send(message);
    });
  });
});
```

It works fine but when I deploy, do I need to set up a another server with websocket connection other than the one React Native provides?

Comment: Do you have any example code to share so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: Does your Web Socket server work if you try connecting to it via a web browser/test client? Are you testing on iOS or Android? I recall that `localhost` works on the iOS emulator but I have a feeling that it doesn't work as expected when using something like Genymotion.